# Merging LiquiBase changesets

Tags: merge, liquibase

I'm developing a system with database version control in LiquiBase. The system is still in pre-alpha development and there are a lot of changes that were reverted or supplemented by other changes (tables removed, columns added and removed).

The current change set reflects the whole development history with many failed experiments, and this whole is rollouted when initializing the database.

Because there is NO release version, I can start from scratch and pull actual DB state in single XML changeset.

Is there a way to tell LiquiBase to merge all change sets into one file, or the only way to do that is per hand?

Comment: afaik liquibase doesn't have function for this...you have to merge the changesets manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use your existing database to generate change log that will be used from now on. For this you can use `generateChangeLog` command from command line, it will generate the changelog file with all the changeSets that represent your current state of the database. You can use this file in your project as initial db creation file, to be used on an empty database. Here's a [link to docs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html).

Comment: I should've noticed there is also generateChangelog method on liquibase.Liquibase class that I use.

Answer (score 3):

There is a page in the Liquibase docs which discusses this scenario in detail:
http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/trimming_changelogs.html

To summarise, they recommend that you don't bother since consolidating your changelogs is both risky and low-reward.

If you do want to push ahead with this, then restarting the changelog using `generateChangeLog`, as suggested by @veljkost, is probably the easiest way. This is documented at http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/existing_project.html

Answer (score 0):

Hence I didn't find automatic solution for this problem in case the changelog is already deployed on several databases in different states, I will describe here my solution for this problem:

1. Generate changelog of your current development state of database using liquibase generate changelog, like:

   ```
   mvn liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.outputChangeLogFile=current_state.yml
   ```
2. Audit generated changelog, check whether it looks good (liquibase is not perfect, it often generates stupid statements). Also if you have in your schema some static data, like dictionaries or so, which were previosuly populated using liquibase, you have to add these to generated changelog as well, you can export data from your database using generate changelog command mentioned above with `-Dliquibase.diffTypes=data` property.
3. Now to prevent the execution of generated changelog (it will obviously fail on existing databases, on prod, test, and other developers local envs), you can do this using for example liquibase `changelogSync`, or using liquibase `contexts`, but all this options require you to do some manual work on every database. You can achieve automatic result by adding the `preConditions` statements for your changeSets.

   - For changesets intended to run on empty databases (changelogs you generated in step 1. above) you can add something like this:

     ```
      preConditions:
       - onFail: MARK_RAN
       - not:
        - tableExists:
            tableName: t_project
     ```

     Where `t_project` is the table name that existed before (most likely this should be table added in first changeSet, so every database which runned at least one changeSet will have this). This will mark generated changelog as run on environments with existing schema, and will run generated changelog for every new database you would like to migrate.
   - Unfortunatelly you have to adjust all legacy changesets as well (I didn't found better solution yet, I did this change using regex and `sed`), you have to add something like that:

     ```
      preConditions:
       - onFail: MARK_RAN
       - tableExists:
           tableName: t_project
     ```

     So opposite condition, from above one. With this all databases which runned at least one changeset in past, will continue to migrate (EXECUTED status of changesets) until changeset generated in step 1. above, and mark generated changesets with MARK_RAN. And for new databases, all previous changesets will be skipped, and first executed will be one generated in step 1. above.

With this solution you can push your merged changelog at any time, and every environment and developer won't have any problem with manual syncing or so.